# ¿Cómo evitar redirección de subdominio al dominio principal en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirección

Tengo una página wordpress **example.com** y un subdominio **sub.example.com**. Ambas peticiones apuntan a /var/www/html. Sin embargo, cuando accedo a **sub.example.com**, ésta me hace una redirección 301 al dominio principal.

```
Status: 301 Moved Permanently
Code:   301
Date:   Mon, 05 Mar 2018 19:13:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:   PHP/7.1.7 ZendServer/9.1.1
Location:   http://example.com/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Utilicé un plugin llamado [Rewrite Rules Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) para verificar si algún plugin tenía algún rewrite rule raro, pero todas las redirecciones son del tipo `index.php?` por lo que no hay razón para que me quite el subdominio. Sin embargo, si ingreso a **sub.example.com/contacto** (por ejemplo), no me hace la redirección 301. Sólo sucede en el subdominio principal. ¿Alguna idea de por qué está sucediendo esto, y dónde podría buscar?

Comment: La regla que publicaste no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con la redirección que estás mencionando... ¿Podrías agregar el código relevante a la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, publico mi .htaccess ya que sé que sería lo primero que solicitarán. No sé qué código necesitaría publicar exactamente, ya que es una instalación Wordpress. No son los plugins, porque decidí desactivarlos todos en un punto, y el problema persistía. Alguna idea?

Comment: menos podemos saber nosotros. Lo único que te puedo decir es que en lo que pusiste en tu pregunta, no hay absolutamente ninguna redirección.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, intentaré seguir buscando dónde ocurre exactamente el error, siento que es algo de wordpress. Si alguien me puede dar una idea de dónde buscar, con gusto subo el código necesario

Comment: ¿Será que la redirección está cacheada en tu navegador? -Eso es lo que sucede con las redirecciones 301, y el porqué no se deben usar a menos de que estés completamente seguro... Te recomendaría probar desde un nuevo navegador/PC con el que no hayas accedido jamás.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta, ya intenté probando con otro navegador, ventana privada he incluso limpiando toda al chaché del navegador y sigue sucediendo. También desactivé todos los plugins de wordpress para asegurarme que no había alguno que hiciera una redirección, pero sigue sucediendo. Alguna otra idea?